# How to Add Data Validation in a Column with leading Zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example I want the data in my Column A to be in 4digits whole number only.

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
0033
0032
```

Now, I've added a data validation in this column,

```
Allow = Whole Number
Min = 0
Max = 9999
```

Now, What if the data contains "0" at the beginning? How can I include this value?

Also, I've tried the formula below but it will not retain the leading zero.

```
=IF(LEN(A1),MOD(A1,1)=0,"")
```

Comment: The data validation with a custom format of `0000` works for me.  I would assume that the numbers you have are text and not numbers.

Comment: @Scott Craner

didnt worked for me. What's the custom formula you;ve used on this?

Comment: He just said.  In the custom format line put `0000` it will make it so the number is always 4 digits adding leading 0s if the number has less then 4 digits.  If there are leading 0s showing up with general formatting then your number is stored as text.

Comment: @gtwebb
I tried 0000 but didn't worked. Also, I dont want do add leading zero if ever  a user will enter "011" so "011" will the the final data.

Comment: Then you are wanting text validation not integer.  because the only way to enter `011` or `0011` is to make the value a text not a number.

Comment: @Scott Craner
What custom formula should I use on this one?

Comment: try `=AND(LEN(A1)<=4,NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(A1))))`

Comment: OR `=AND(LEN(A1)<=4,ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1)))`

Comment: @Scott Craner still not showing the leading zero :(

Comment: again it will need to be entered as text so put `'` in front of the number as it is entered. so `'011` or `'0011`.  Excel can not interpolate.  You can set up a mask for four digits or three digits but not both.

Comment: You can set the entire column to Text format and Excel will put the `'` in front automatically.